# datepicker date format...I've read the other posts

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to re-format the date input that I am getting from my date picker.....

Here is the code that I have within a section of the body

```
<div class="simpleTabsContent">PLACEHOLDER: Linux Update
           Date: <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker">
           <br>
           <button type="button" onclick="myFunc2()">Button Text...click me </button>
           <p id="test"></p>
           <script>
              function myFunc2(){
                var x;
                x = $(".selector").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'}).val();
                //x = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
              }
           </script>
     </div>
```

This is the code I have within my head...

```
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SPUI Development</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
     @import "css/style.css";
  </style>
  <!-- SimpleTabs -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/simpletabs_1.3.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
     @import "css/simpletabs.css";
  </style>
  <!-- Code for calendar -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
     $.datepicker.setDefaults(
        $.extend ($.datepicker.regional[''])
     );
     $('#datepicker').datepicker();
   });
  </script>
```

I can't tell what I am doing wrong. Someone please help? I also did read the api and several stack overflow examples along with online examples....I am lost.

Comment: You have no `<input class="selector">`.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN alter the format after your datePicker is instantiated. You just forgot the keyword `option`:

```
x = $("#datepicker").datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see right away that you don't have an element with class `selector`

```
x = $(".selector").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'}).val();
```

Did you mean

```
x = $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'}).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only provide options like `dateFormat:` when you first initialize the datepicker, which is in the `$(function() {...})`. It should be:

```
$(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults(
        $.extend ($.datepicker.regional[''])
    );
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

Then your other function can be:

```
function myFunc2(){
    var x;
    x = $("#datepicker").val();
    $("#test").text(x);
}
```

You don't need to call `.datepicker()` here. When the user selects something from the datepicker, it's put into the value of the input element.

If you want to change the options of a jQuery UI widget on the fly after initialization, you do it using the `option` or `options` methods:

```
$("#datepicker").option("dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
```

But this doesn't seem necessary for what you're doing.